# upgrading to identity 2.0 EF migration issue

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

I am a little stuck.

I have an application that I have just updated the AspNet.Identity to 2.0, in order to take advantage of the new password reset methods. The application uses sql azure too.

One issue I faced was that I had a property in my ApplicationUser class called EmailAddress. Now that Identity has the property an Email property, I decided to remove this and created a migration to update my database. When I ran it against my local sql server this worked fine. The migration looks like this:

```
public partial class EmailFieldChange : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Sql("UPDATE dbo.AspNetUsers SET Email = EmailAddress");
        DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "EmailAddress");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "EmailAddress", c => c.String());
        Sql("UPDATE dbo.AspNetUsers SET EmailAddress = Email");
    }
}
```

however I am now trying to publish my changes to azure, and I am reciving the following error:

> Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again.
>   Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Which is all well and good, but the EmailAddress field was not indexed!! The only index on the table is on the Id field which I have not touched. All my googling leads me to issues with people trying to change the primary key which I am not doing

Can anyone give me any insight on this?

Edit:

I have also now tried this, with no success.

```
        Sql("UPDATE dbo.AspNetUsers SET Email = EmailAddress");
        CreateIndex("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Id", true, "PK_dbo.AspNetUsers");
        DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "EmailAddress");
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a clustered index to the table? Looks like the azure sql needs it in order to work [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

Comment: the Id property already has a clustered index and there is another non-clustered one on Username. I have not specifically added these, so I assume they have come from AspNet.Identity

Comment: SQL Azure requires a clustered index on every table. I can't imagine the new version of Identity would drop an index on the table and recreate it during an operation but I guess it's possible. Perhaps recreate the table explicitly with the index so you know there is no cruft there and retry?

Comment: Okay so I solved this in the end by recreating the entire migration as an SQL script and using the suspend index feature to allow me to change the FK. Ugly, but job done.